# my SVN add command takes too long

Tags: svn

I want to add all unversioned files to SVN, to do that I run:
svn add C:/Versions/myWorkingCopy/ --parents --force

It takes it way too long to finish,  even when there is nothing new to add.
I suspect its this "--force" flag which makes the add be recursive.

Note that:

```
1) My working copy is huge (190,533 Files, 30GB).

2) I am running SVN 1.9.4.

3) My working copy includes also 2 external folders (I don't know if its related or not).
```

Any idea how to make this process faster? svn status finishes fast so I dont understand why it takes it so long to SVN add when there are no files to add.

Comment: Get a faster disk? You're talking about moving a **lot** of data around and a lot of processing of that data just to add it to the working copy. `svn status` does a lot less work than `svn add`, so it stands to reason that it would be faster.

Comment: @alroc but if svn can know immediately that there is nothing to add (we can see that svn status finishes in less than a second) so why does the add command takes so long?